# How to add 2010 workflow in list using client object model

Tags: designer-workflow, approval

I want to add approval 2010 workflow to SharePoint 2013 list using client object model.I tried the below approach but it didn't worked.
I am using Angularjs and this code is not working in it.

```
 var context = new ClientContext( url );
 Web site = context.Web;
 var query = context.LoadQuery( site.WorkflowTemplates.Where( x => x.Name ==    "My Template Name" ) );
 context.ExecuteQuery();
 WorkflowTemplate wfTemplate = query.Single();
 var wfc = new WorkflowAssociationCreationInformation();
 wfc.HistoryList = site.Lists.GetByTitle( "Workflow History" );
 wfc.Name = "My Workflow Name";
 wfc.TaskList = site.Lists.GetByTitle( "Tasks" );
 wfc.Template = wfTemplate;
 List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle( "List Name" );
 WorkflowAssociation wf = list.WorkflowAssociations.Add( wfc );
 wf.AllowManual = false; // is never updated
 wf.AutoStartChange = false; // is never updated
 wf.AutoStartCreate = true; // is never updated
 wf.Enabled = true; // is never updated
 string assocData = GetAssociationXml(); // internal method
 wf.AssociationData = assocData; // is never updated
 context.Load( wf );
 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following...

```
    var context = new ClientContext(url);
    Web site = context.Web;
    var query = context.LoadQuery(site.WorkflowTemplates.Where(x => x.Name == "My Template Name"));
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    WorkflowTemplate wfTemplate = query.Single();
    var wfc = new WorkflowAssociationCreationInformation();
    wfc.HistoryList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Workflow History");
    wfc.Name = "My Workflow Name";
    wfc.TaskList = site.Lists.GetByTitle("Tasks");
    wfc.Template = wfTemplate;
    List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle("List Name");
    WorkflowAssociation wf = list.WorkflowAssociations.Add(wfc);
    wf.AllowManual = false; // is never updated
    wf.AutoStartChange = false; // is never updated
    wf.AutoStartCreate = true; // is never updated
    wf.Enabled = true; // is never updated
    string assocData = GetAssociationXml(); // internal method
    wf.AssociationData = assocData; // is never updated
    wf.Update();
    list.Update();
    context.Load(wf);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try out this    

static void attachWorkflow(ClientContext context,string listname)
    {

    try
    {
    Web site = context.Web;
    //var query = context.LoadQuery(site.WorkflowTemplates);
    var query = context.LoadQuery(site.WorkflowTemplates.Where(x => x.Name == “DiscussionTemplate”));
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    WorkflowTemplate wfTemplate = query.Single();
    var wfc = new WorkflowAssociationCreationInformation();
    wfc.HistoryList = site.Lists.GetByTitle(“Workflow History”);
    wfc.Name = “DiscussionTemplate1”;
    wfc.TaskList = site.Lists.GetByTitle(“Tasks”);
    wfc.Template = wfTemplate;
    List list = site.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);
    WorkflowAssociation wf = list.WorkflowAssociations.Add(wfc);
    wf.AllowManual = false; // is never updated
    wf.AutoStartChange = true; // is never
    wf.AutoStartCreate = true; // is never updated
    wf.Enabled = true; // is never updated
    //string assocData = GetAssociationXml(); // internal method
    // wf.AssociationData = assocData; // is never updated
    wf.Update();
    context.Load(wf);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Common.strServiceLog, “Error in attaching the Workflow: ” + ex.Message + ” for ” + boardName + ” at time : ” + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    }
```

[Reference](https://ahujadhiraj.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/attach-a-workflow-to-the-list-using-client-object-model/)